# ZODB broken instance

Tags: python, python-3.x, zodb

I am trying to persist an object reference using **only ZODB** in a **FileStorage** database.
I made a test to analyze its performance, but the object when it is loaded it appears to be broken.

**The test consists on:**

1. *create an object in one script and write it to database.*
2. *In another script read that object from the same database and use it there.*

[zodb1.py image from CMD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/POISw.png)

[zodb2.py image from CMD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jI0Zr.png)

**zodb1.py**

```
import ZODB
from ZODB.FileStorage import FileStorage
import persistent
import transaction

storage = FileStorage('ODB.fs')
db = ZODB.DB(storage)
connection = db.open()
ODB = connection.root()

print(ODB)

class Instrument(persistent.Persistent):

    def __init__(self, name, address):
        self.name = name
        self.address = address
    
    def __str__(self):
        return f'Instrument - {self.name}, ID: {self.address}'

camera = Instrument(name='Logitech', address='CAM0')


ODB['camera'] = camera
ODB._p_changed = True
transaction.commit()

print(ODB)

ob = ODB['camera']
print(ob)
print(dir(ob))
```

**zodb2.py**

```
import ZODB, ZODB.FileStorage
import persistent
import transaction

connection = ZODB.connection('ODB.fs')

ODB = connection.root()

print(ODB)

ob = ODB['camera']
print(ob)
print(dir(ob))
```

Am I missing something important? I've read the ZODB's documentation and I see no other configuration process or another way to aproach this.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem you see is because `zodb2.py` has no knowledge of the `Instrument` class defined in `zodb1.py`.

I guess that if you moved your class to a separate module and imported it in both `zodb1` and `zodb2`, you would not see a broken object.